# How to use Stack and Positioned in Column

Tags: flutter

Need to adjust the position of the Flatbutton and IconButton in Raw. How to use **Stack** and **Positioned** in the below code. is it possible to apply stack and positioned in this code?

```
    return MaterialApp(
  home: Scaffold(
    body: Column(children: [
      FlatButton( // `need to position in bottom right side`
          color: Colors.green,
          textColor: Colors.black,
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          onPressed: () {},
          child: Text(
            'Save',
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
          )),
      Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            child: GestureDetector(
              child: IconButton( // `need to position in center`
                  icon: Icon(Icons.mic),
                  color: Colors.black,
                  iconSize: 50,
                  onPressed: () async {
                    startRecord();
                  }),
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: GestureDetector(
              child: IconButton( // `need to position in bottom center'
                icon: Icon(Icons.pause),
                color: Colors.black,
                iconSize: 50,
                onPressed: () {
                  pauseRecord();
                },
              ),
            ),
          ),
          RecordMp3.instance.status == RecordStatus.PAUSE
              ? Expanded(
                  child: GestureDetector(
                    child: IconButton(
                      icon: Icon(Icons.play_arrow),
                      color: Colors.black,
                      iconSize: 50,
                      onPressed: () {
                        resumeRecord();
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                )
              : SizedBox(),
          Expanded(
            child: GestureDetector(
              child: IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.stop),
                color: Colors.black,
                iconSize: 50,
                onPressed: () {
                  stopRecord();
                },
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0),
        child: Text(
          statusText,
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red, fontSize: 20),
        ),
      ),
      isComplete && recordFilePath != null
          ? Expanded(
              child: GestureDetector(
                child: IconButton( // `need to position in between bottom and middle`
                    icon: Icon(Icons.play_circle_filled),
                    color: Colors.black,
                    iconSize: 50,
                    onPressed: () {
                      play();
                    }),
              ),
            )
          : SizedBox(),
    ]),
  ),
);
```

need to position the Flatbutton in the right bottom. need to position the Iconbuttons in middle and space between the middle and bottom.

Comment: The question is unclear and also looks incomplete. Where is the `IconButton` in the code? What exactly is the layout you are trying to achieve? In layout-related questions, usually some kind of visual helps a lot to understand the goal and the problem.

Comment: @JigarPatel added more code, please check